# Auto selecting chosen post-per-page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I've created the ability to have posts per page on a gallery of images. It's working fine but I wanted to add a little feature, but I can't figure out an elegant solution.

If a user selects a specific number, say 200, I wanted the select box to automatically show the chosen number on subsequent pages. So the user can see the change happen.

I'm kind of new to PHP so maybe I'm missing an obvious trick. I know I could do a massive `if` `else` statement for each option like this:

```
<?php if($posts == 25) { ?>

    <option value="">Pics Per Page</option>
    <option value="25" selected>25 Pics</option>
    <option value="50">50 Pics</option>
    <option value="100">100 Pics</option>
    <option value="200">200 Pics</option>

<?php } else if($posts == 50 ) { ?>

    <option value="">Pics Per Page</option>
    <option value="25">25 Pics</option>
    <option value="50" selected>50 Pics</option>
    <option value="100">100 Pics</option>
    <option value="200">200 Pics</option>

<?php } else if... etc. etc.
```

But this is a bit long winded and I'm sure there's a more elegant solution?

Comment: Are you using any type of framework? most frameworks has html generating functions that will do this for you

Comment: You should check what WP has to offer, for instance : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
$options = array(25, 50, 100, 200);

echo '<option value="" disabled="disabled">Pics Per Page</option>';
foreach ( $options as $option ) {
  $selected = $posts == $option ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
  echo '<option value="' . $option . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $option . ' Pics</option>';
}
```